React Material UI and react hook form clear button dynamic component
I want to write a custom React TextField component and I want to add a clear button to this custom component. I added the button but its functionality does not work. I share the call and content of the Custom Component below.

  const { handleSubmit, control, formState } = useForm<SignInModel>({
    resolver: zodResolver(signinSchema),
    defaultValues: signinDefaultValue,
  });

<Controller
                name="email"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
                  <ValidationTextField
                    label={t("auth.email")}
                    type="email"
                    autoComplete="email"
                    helperText={!!errors.email && (isDirty || isSubmitted) ? String(errors.email.message) : null}
                    {...field}
                  />
                )}
              />

interface ValidationTextFieldProps
  extends Omit<FilledTextFieldProps, "variant"> {}

export function ValidationTextField(props: ValidationTextFieldProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");


  return (
    <TextField
      required
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth
      helperText={props.helperText}
      error={!!props.helperText}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
      FormHelperTextProps={{
        style: { width: "fit-content", marginRight: 0 },
      }}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: !!props.value && (
          <IconButton
            aria-label="toggle password visibility"
            onClick={() =>{ setValue("") }}
          >
            <CancelRoundedIcon />
          </IconButton>
        ),
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}




Your ...field and ...props contain value and onChange, so you shouldn't have the value state in the component at all.
It should look like this:
export function ValidationTextField(props: ValidationTextFieldProps) {

  return (
    <TextField
      required
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth
      helperText={props.helperText}
      error={!!props.helperText}
      FormHelperTextProps={{
        style: { width: "fit-content", marginRight: 0 },
      }}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: !!props.value && (
          <IconButton
            aria-label="toggle password visibility"
            onClick={() =>{ props.onChange("") }}
          >
            <CancelRoundedIcon />
          </IconButton>
        ),
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

Note that:

I removed const [value, setValue] = useState("");
I removed the value and onChange that you were passing directly your TextField - they were being overridden anyway by what was in props
I changed your endAdornment to call props.onChange("") instead of setValue("")

To better understand this, add console.log(props) and take a look at what's being passed to your component

Where I call the custom component, it gives an error of definition type like onChange={() => resetField("email")}. Error message: "'onChange' was specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.ts"

@durmusyasar this sounds like a separate issue, not one that has to do with my answer. Keep in mind that the field argument in the Controller render prop contains an onChange prop, so if  trying to pass another one where you are rendering the ValidationTextField, you’ll see that error. That wasn’t in your original question, though, or my answer
